# Stl unordered multimaps with tuple

Tags: c++, stl

Basically ,I want hash table with link list which stores 3 int type variable so I am using unordered multimap with int and tuple .But its giving me compile time error WHERE I AM DOING WRONG .And is there any other efficient way of doing this . And further i want to find min on imposing some conditions on b and c in all the list contained in the buckets.For this I am thinking to use stl min method of algorithms but I am not able to figure out how to send second and third data of tuple as an argument for lambda function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::unordered_multimap<int, std::tuple<int, int, int>> um;

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int n, d;
        cin>>n>>d;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int a, b, c;
            cin >> a >> b >> c;
            um.insert(make_pair(a, std::make_tuple(a, b, c)));
        }
    }
    for (std::unordered_multimap<int, std::tuple<int, int, int>>::const_iterator i = um.begin(); i != um.end(); ++i) {
        cout << i->second->get<1> << endl;
    }
}
```

this the error when i am just trying to print values

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:34:18: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'const             std::tuple'
cout<second ->get<1><main.cpp:35:3: error: expected declaration before    '}' token
}}
^
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please format your code a bit, it's kinda hard to read.

Comment: I am unable to figure out how to access  send values contained in  the tuple  to  a lambda function eg.
my tuple has values <0,1,6>
ad i want to send 1 and 6 to lambda function [ ]

Comment: _@abhudyasingh_ Just as @Nathan said. Please [edit] your question and show us the error message as verbatim text.

Comment: `i->second ->get<1>` should be `i->second.get<1>()`, the compiler error is pretty clear about it.

Comment: @abhudyasingh Also `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is a very bad idea.

Comment: main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:35:18: error: 'const class std::tuple' has no member named 'get'
  cout<second.get<1><main.cpp:36:3: error: expected declaration before '}' token
  }}

Comment: Now on fixing it i am getting above error

Comment: @Frank It would be if `get` was actually a member function, but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
cout << i->second->get<1> << endl;
```

`i` is an iterator to a `std::unordered_multimap<int, std::tuple<int, int, int>>`.  That means that `i->second` gives you the `std::tuple<int, int, int>` part of the key/value pair.  Since it is not a pointer you do not use `->` to access it's members but instead you use `.`.

That said `get` is not a member function of `std::tuple`.  [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) is a global function and you pass the tuple to it to get its element.  That would make you code look like

```
std::cout << std::get<1>(i->second) << std::endl;
```

Comment: And likewise can i pass these values to lambda functions